# What does catalina_service.bat do?

Tags: webserver, xampp, tomcat

Are installing [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html), there are three files related to catalina in the main folder:

1. `catalina_start.bat`
2. `catalina_service.bat`
3. `catalina_stop.bat`

I understand that catalina_start and catalina_stop starts and stops the web server respectively. But what does `catalina_service.bat` do? When I double click it, it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Catalina is Tomcat's Servlet container. so this bat file probably installs it as a Windows service.

Comment: @Kwaio, what does a "windows service" mean? Isn't it just a program?

Comment: It's a program running under windows service containers, that automatically starts with the OS, and is automatically restarted upon failure, just like unix daemons. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used it myself. But i think it installs tomcat as a service in windows services.msc . Hence you don't see anything when clicking on it. Goto run and type services.msc to verify. Also it doesnt hurt to look into that .bat file in notepad and see what it does, usually it is only few of lines long.

Comment: I can run services.msc, but I don't see Tomcat listed. How do I verify if it installs tomcat as a service in windows services.msc?

Comment: @Pacerier , if you open the catalina_service.bat in notepad, you will see a service name it installs and you can see in services.msc if the same named one is available.

Comment: The content of the file is at http://shrib.com/iBzz3Cq1 , it doesn't install any service right?

Comment: It does install service, but open command prompt and call this bat file. You will see messages like installing service or any failures in installing service. IMHO, this bat file is unnecessarily big for what it does. It does use a lot of variables and error checking.

Comment: Even if I open command prompt and call the bat file, it closes itself automatically...

Comment: @Pacerier Did you call the bat file from inside command prompt (Not by  clicking it) ?

Comment: Yes. definitely.